# What firmware type to use for FLSUN 3D printer in PrusaSlicer setup?

Tags: firmware, prusaslicer, flsun-3d-cube

I have a FLSUN printer: [3D Printer DIY Kit Auto Leveling Cube Full Metal Square Large printing size 260X260X350 with heated Bed Precision](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071NZSF33).

I plan on using PrusaSlicer as slicer (found it in Ubuntu.)

I now need to pick a Firmware Type in the setup screen. Which one should I select? I vaguely  remember it should be RepRap, but I'm not sure.

[image: PrusaSlicer Configuration Wizard]

Comment: Does the printer not display the firmware name and revision when it powers up? It is probably either Repetier or Marlin.

Comment: I never turned it on. I guess it is time to do so! I will do this next week...

Comment: Most common is RepRap, as most printers use Marlin, which implements the RepRap code Style.